# phpPgAdmin on OpenShift is not accessible from application URL

Tags: postgresql, rss, openshift, phppgadmin

Installed this (https://github.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-origin-cartridge-phppgadmin) to my Tiny Tiny RSS application on OpenShift to manage my database.* However, after the installation and a few restarts, .../phppgadmin/ URL gives me 404 error. Any ideas? Could it be the github cartridge is using old environmental variables? Thanks!

*The reason I want to install phppgadmin in the first place is to vacuum my ever-expanding database on Tiny Tiny RSS application. `vacuumdb` and `vacuumdb -f -a` only claim ~50mb and `app-tidy` does ~100mb, as opposed to ~600mb previously. So, I need to find another solution, like phppgadmin, to address my quota limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using phppgadmin, it would be a much better idea to download pgadmin onto your computer and then use the rhc port-forward command to connect to your database and do your maintenance.  That cartridge is pretty old and likely will not get updated anytime soon (or ever).

Comment: Thank you. Was successfully able to connect my database and run `vacuum`, which unfortunately didn't solve my problem of quota. Anyways, cheers.